# SQL Server Agent Job secure password

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, security, sql-agent-job

I have a SQL Server Agent Job which connects to another SQL Server from a Powershell script. Currently, I need to pass the credentials as parameters to the Powershell script but it is in plain text format.

I want to somehow secure it. Is there any way I can secure the password or hide it?

Below is the screenshot of how it looks right now:

[image]

Comment: You won't be able to do that in Agent. I would suggest that you probably need to look at a different application you can automate your task in.

Comment: `-src_auth_type  "windows"` implies you are using windows authentication so you don't actually need credentials. It really depends on what the script does. SQL Agent runs under a windows account and you should be able to use that. This smells like it's more complicated than it needs to be. What does `Sync.ps1` do? can you post the source code?

Comment: Are you limited to SQL Server authentication or can you add/reuse an AD account on the target machine?

Comment: Use Windows Authentication with an AD account

Comment: You could use the windows credential store on the server - and pull the password from there based on the username passed into the script.  Lookup Get-StoredCredential for examples.